# Viewing fullsized image on same page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm attempting to make it so that the images on my web page when clicked, will show a fullsized image. However, my `javascript` doesn't seem to be happy with what I have in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Trasiva/guJGB/).

I have to use the source of the image due to my images being linked to a `pagegridview` in ASP.Net, and I have it linked to a property I called imgFull. The code on the fiddle is for testing, my actual code is below:

CSS:

```
#overlay{
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    background-color: #000; 
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 70) !important;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("img").click(function(){                                          
    $("#imgBig").attr("src", $(this).attr('fullImg'));
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#overlayContent").show();
});

$("#imgBig").click(function(){
    $("#imgBig").attr("src", "");
    $("#overlay").hide();
    $("#overlayContent").hide();
});
```

HTML in ASP.NET:

```
<!-- Divs for displaying the full sized image. Initially hidden. Hides again when clicked -->
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="overlayContent">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgFull" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" Width="400" ImageUrl="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" CssClass="imgBig"/>
</div>
```

Javascript is not my forte, as soon as this project is over I intend on taking some time to learn it but at present, I have to go with the "Drink from a fire hose" approach and hope I can retain what I'm using. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo:

```
$("#imgSmall").click(function(){                                                
    $("#imgBig").attr("src"; $(this).attr('src'));
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#overlayContent").show();
});
```

The semicolon in your assignment to `src` should be a comma:

```
$("#imgSmall").click(function(){                                                
    $("#imgBig").attr("src", $(this).attr('src'));
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#overlayContent").show();
});
```

One of the first things you should learn is to use your browser's developer tools. Chrome has wonderful tools baked in (Hit F12), but Firebug for Firefox is also great for Javascript debugging.

Comment: True, but I usually steer people to Chrome or Firefox where possible, as I find their tools more mature.

Comment: @ChrisHardie Oddly, the demonstration code above still fails despite it having a comma instead of semicolon. The overlay grays out the page fine, but the image itself fails to show. The fiddle was what I was using for testing, the code I placed in my question is the primary focus due to that being the "live" code so to speak.

Comment: @ChrisHardie Well, looking using the debug tools in Chrome, the image isn't being named fullImg, it's being named `ctl00_Main_imgFull`. That's the issue here, when I set the Google image as the default source for imgFull, it isn't being placed OVER the overlay for some reason...

Comment: Your image is being placed in a naming container in your ASP.Net page. You can either A) Not use a server control for the image B) Use the `ClientId` or `CssClass` properties to get more predictable selectors.

Comment: @ChrisHardie So go with something more along the lines of    `$(""<%=imgBig.ClientID%>").attr("src", $(this).attr('fullImg'));`?

Comment: Alright, It's still having some issues, but I think I've taken enough of your time. Thanks for putting up with a sick, javascript illiterate.